# MYSQL select sales people who represent different studios (without duplicates)

Tags: mysql, sql

so I need to list the salesID, firstName, lastName of each sales person who represents a different studio where I have the following (this is from the SalesPeople table)

```
   +---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
   | SalesID | firstName | LastName | StudioName          |
   +---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
   |       1 | Bob       | Bentley  | MakeTrax            |
   |       1 | Bob       | Bentley  | Lone Star Recording |
   |       1 | Bob       | Bentley  | Pacific Rim         |
   |       2 | Lisa      | Williams | MakeTrax            |
   |       2 | Lisa      | Williams | Lone Star Recording |
   |       2 | Lisa      | Williams | Pacific Rim         |
   |       3 | Clint     | Sanchez  | MakeTrax            |
   |       3 | Clint     | Sanchez  | Lone Star Recording |
   |       3 | Clint     | Sanchez  | Pacific Rim         |
   |       4 | Scott     | Bull     | MakeTrax            | 
   |       4 | Scott     | Bull     | Lone Star Recording |
   |       4 | Scott     | Bull     | Pacific Rim         |
   +---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

so what I'm trying to get is just three records displaying sales people for the three different studios

`**I've tried**`

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.SalesID, a.FirstName, a.LastName, b.StudioName FROM SalesPeople a JOIN Studios b;
```

but I get this

```
   +---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
   | SalesID | firstName | LastName | StudioName          |
   +---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
   |       1 | Bob       | Bentley  | MakeTrax            |
   |       1 | Bob       | Bentley  | Lone Star Recording |
   |       1 | Bob       | Bentley  | Pacific Rim         |
   |       2 | Lisa      | Williams | MakeTrax            |
   |       3 | Clint     | Sanchez  | Lone Star Recording |
   |       3 | Clint     | Sanchez  | Pacific Rim         |
   |       4 | Scott     | Bull     | MakeTrax            |
   |       4 | Scott     | Bull     | Lone Star Recording |
   |       4 | Scott     | Bull     | Pacific Rim         |
   +---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

how do I make the distinction to find three separate people representing one studio?

Comment: Post desired output too. And why are you joining `SalesPeople a JOIN Studios b`?

Comment: Have you tried removing the StudioName from your distinct?

Comment: To give an answer we need to know your database schema, at the very least what these tables have in common.

Comment: @EternalHour the two tables are connected by the field StudioID I have a diagram of how the database is set up if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the StudioName from your distinct.

Comment: yes this worked, I feel like such a noob for not noticing that